# Non-English language Mathematical podcasts/audio

Tags: math-communication, soft-question

Following on from this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2507/mathematical-podcasts-audio), does anyone know of any good quality non-English language mathematical podcasts? I'm particularly interested in anything relating to the history of mathematics.

I'm already aware of [Canal Académie's](http://www.canalacademie.com/idm1159-+-Mathematiques-+.html) collection in French, which includes, amongst others, the following interesting broadcasts:

[Henri Cartan et la fondation du groupe Bourbaki](http://www.canalacademie.com/ida3791-Henri-Cartan-et-la-fondation-du.html) and
[Jacques Tits, mathématicien, prix Abel 2008](http://www.canalacademie.com/ida2965-Jacques-Tits-mathematicien-prix.html).

I'm interested in anything in Spanish and Italian, as well as French.

I haven't yet had time to browse the suggestions offered in the previous question, but I wish I'd seen it earlier as twice in the last year non-English speaking (as a mother tongue) friends have asked me for similar suggestions in English and I wasn't able to help at the time.